# How to redirect subfolder without index file to 404?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, server

My case is example.com/js/, example.com/images/, example.com/css/, example.com/assets/. These four url ("js", "images", "css" and "assets" subdirectories) haven't index page there. I hope to redirect visitor to 404 page when they access example.com/js/, example.com/images/, example.com/css/, example.com/assets/.

My 404 page is ready, the url is /error404.html.

Here is what I try to add in my .htacess but not work.

```
<Files "assets/*">
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/error404.html
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
</Files>
<Files "images/*">
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/error404.html
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
</Files>
<Files "js/*">
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/error404.html
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
</Files>
<Files "css/*">
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/error404.html
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 /error404.html
```

It's fine.